# What's wrong with my sub-classed AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone

I sub-classed AVAudioPlayer like so:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer {
    // irrelevant objects...
}
-(void) myMethod;
@end
```

I also placed myMethod in the implementation.  In another class, I instantiate the sub-class (not AVAudioPlayer) and import the header.

When I attempt to call myMethod, I get the error:

[AVAudioPlayer myMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I'm certain I created an AudioPlayer class, not AVAudioPlayer, so what gives?

Comment: try printing the [audioplayer class] soon after you create the object.. that might give you some idea.

Comment: duh, found it.  I was making a reference to AudioPlayer but allocating AVAudioPlayer.  Ugh.

Comment: post your answer and I'll check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) easy to check the type of the object soon after its created. looks like the [audioplayer class] trick worked